# CURL MULTI - why two loops?

Tags: php, curl

Can anybody help me understand why are there two loops here?

```
 <?php
// create both cURL resources
$ch1 = curl_init();
$ch2 = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, "http://lxr.php.net/");
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.php.net/");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

//create the multiple cURL handle
$mh = curl_multi_init();

//add the two handles
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch1);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch2);

$active = null;
//execute the handles
do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    }
}

//close the handles
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch1);
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch2);
curl_multi_close($mh);

?>
```

Code is taken from http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php - the first example

Another issue is that the code strangely outputs everything to screen which never happened when using curl without the multi_exec feature. I needed to echo the content before, but not for this one, its blurts out everything without even asking.

Comment: bcoa there are two different `UR`L and two different `curl object` exists

Comment: No, that's not why. the multi interface "drives" many simultaneous ones in the same loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no good explanation for that. It can indeed be moved into a single loop.

I believe this example code originates from demo code we did in plain C in the curl project that made that first call/loop to see if it should go on or not.

You can easily rewrite the code to use just a single loop.

Comment: i tried removing the first do while loop and it does not work.

Comment: well you need to use some intelligence as well not just delete some lines! the while() condition on the second loop needs to match the first time it gets there as of course otherwise it will never run

Comment: one more than, why does it output everything to screen?

Comment: it is an _example_, you need to alter it as you see fit